# Cocos2dx CCTableView issue

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have made a drop down list using CCTableView. Its working quite ok. Now i have to hide the table when i select any entry. So i have written following code.

```
void Sample1::tableCellTouched(CCTableView* table, CCTableViewCell* cell)
{    
     CCLOG("cell touched at index: %i", cell->getIdx());
     table->setVisible(false);
}
```

When this is executed the table becomes invisible, but when i try to again make it visible it(CCTableView) doesn't respond to any touches, while the other buttons are responding.

Can anyone guess what might be going wrong!?

Comment: How did you add a cell to your CCTableView? Can you share?

Answer (score 0):

It's because CCTableView itself checks if it's visible and won't process touches if it's invisible.
Here the responsible section in CCTableView.cpp:

```
if (!this->isVisible()) {
    return;
}
```

This snippet is both in `ccTouchBegan` and `ccTouchEnded`.

Your delegate's `tableCellTouched` will be called inside CCTableView's `ccTouchEnded`, so you would have to make your table visible in a function that is not dependent on calls from CCTableView.

Answer (score 0):

For adding Tablecell in CCTable

Make a class named CustomClass:

In CustomClass.cpp

CCTableCell* CustomClass::tableMethod(CCTable* pTable, unsigned int idx)

{

CCTableCell* tableCell = pTable->dequeueCell();

```
if(!tableCell)
{
    tableCell = new CCTableCell();
```

addChild(tableCell);

```
}
```

return tableCell;

}